# Bizarre behavior when receiving a Model (with a IEnumerable property) from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm facing an odd behavior.
Keeping it simple, I've got this method within a controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
   var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);

   var userEvents = context.Events
       .Where(e => e.AppIdentityUserId == user.Id)
       .AsEnumerable();

   return View(userEvents);
}
```

and this model:

```
public class Event
{
    //other properties
    public IEnumerable<Participant> ParticipantsList { get; set; }
}
```

When my View receives that model, ParticipantsList is null.
So I write a test query, to observe what is happening.

```
foreach (var event in userEvents)
    test = context.Participants.Where(p => p.EventId == event.Id).AsEnumerable();
```

The query successfully retrieves that info

[image: test successful results]

And this happens

[image: list now filled]

So, this time, I add a breakpoint to each iteration of foreach loop, expanding test results in each break, except last

[image: only the lists which the corresponding test I expanded have results now]

As you can see, it only fills when I expand the corresponding test. And if I expand the event results before test, the list remains null.

I'd like to understand why is it happening, so that I can fix this and any related problem in the future.

I hope I managed to clarify what's going on. It proved to be a challenge to do so properly.

Comment: can you replace your events call with the following `var userEvents = context.Events       .Where(e => e.AppIdentityUserId == user.Id).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is lazily evaluated. If nothing iterates it, the implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` does not execute.

By evaluating the value in your debugger, you cause that code to run.

If you wish to always materialize your database query, regardless of whether the result is actually used, replace `.AsEnumerable()` with `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`.

As for why it seems to be null in your view, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213184/ienumerable-model-from-view-to-controller-is-null/51215259) may provide guidance.

Comment: Changing to `.ToList()` didn't actually solve the problem, but I added a query to get all matching  itens from DbSet (them adding `ToList()`). Didn't need to pass anything else to my View, though. I wonder if changing my model property to `IList<Participant>` or `List<Participant>` would have fixed it.